# How to convert all numbers regardless of decimal separator into valid number of current locale?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I have a column with text looking like this:

```
123,123
123.123
123,123
123.123
```

I would like another column to parse this into decimal numbers, disregarding the different decimal separators (dot **.** and comma **,**) so the result would be like this when locale has dot as separator:

```
123.123
123.123
123.123
123.123
```

And like this when locale has comma as separator:

```
123,123
123,123
123,123
123,123
```

How can I do this in the simplest way possible in Google Sheets?

Comment: Are original values always three characters before and after the dot or comma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following formula does the job (tested with U.S. and Russia as locales, where separators are different):

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ",", ".")), VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", ",")))
```

Explanation:

- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) returns the first argument unless it throws an error, in which case it returns the second.
- The first argument of `IFERROR` is the result of converting the text, with any commas replaced by dots, into a number.
- The second argument of `IFERROR` is the result of converting the text, with any dots replaced by commas, into a number.

I'm assuming that in every locale, one of two things is going to work.

Comment: Since today this seems not to work anymore

Comment: And how / where does one apply the function? .. and is it just a one of or permanent "execution on change"?

I just imported a CSV file with bank statements and need gsuite to see them as numbers instead of strings.

search replace "." with "#" 
search replace "," with "."
search replace "#" with ","

In selection

Comment: Joined community just to say that inside the formula we need semicolon instead of comma!

Answer (score 0):

## For all numbers

Whether they are using thoudsand and comma separators or not (e.g. 1,000,000.00 or 1.000.000,00)

```
=IFERROR(
    VALUE(A1),
    IFERROR(
        VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E1, ".", "~"), ",", "."), "~", ",")),
        VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E1, ",", "~"), ".", ","), "~", "."))
    )
)
```

In a single line:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(A1),IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", "~"), ",", "."), "~", ",")), VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", "~"), ".", ","), "~", "."))))
```

As an ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(A1:A),IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, ".", "~"), ",", "."), "~", ",")), VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, ",", "~"), ".", ","), "~", ".")))))
```

**For currencies**

In a single line:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"€","")),IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"€",""), ".", "~"), ",", "."), "~", ",")), VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"€",""), ",", "~"), ".", ","), "~", "."))))
```

As an ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,"€","")),IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,"€",""), ".", "~"), ",", "."), "~", ",")), VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,"€",""), ",", "~"), ".", ","), "~", ".")))))
```